# Why in console even numbers gives empty list?

Tags: dart

```
void  main() {
    List<int> numbers = [55,58,62,15,14,19,20]; 
    List oddNumbers = []; 
    List evenNumbers = [];

    for (int index = 0; index < numbers.length; index++) {
        print(numbers[index]);
        if(numbers[index]% 2 !=0) {
            oddNumbers.add(numbers[index]);
        } else if(numbers[index]%2 != 0) {
            evenNumbers.add(numbers[index]);
        }
    }
    print("Odd numbers:$oddNumbers");
    print("Even numbers:$evenNumbers");
}
```

it gives:

```
Odd numbers:[55, 15, 19]
Even numbers:[]
```

Why the even numbers list is empty?

Comment: You have the same condition in both your if clauses - Just remove the if in the else clause of your logic, it's redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi You're using same logic in both if and else conditions. Please check below snippet.

```
if(numbers[index]% 2 !=0) { 
oddNumbers.add(numbers[index]); } else 
if(numbers[index]%2 == 0) { 
evenNumbers.add(numbers[index]); } }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int index = 0; index < numbers.length; index++) {
    if(numbers[index]% 2 !=0) {
        oddNumbers.add(numbers[index]);
    } else if(numbers[index]% 2 != 1) {
        evenNumbers.add(numbers[index]);
    }
}
print("Odd numbers:$oddNumbers");
print("Even numbers:$evenNumbers");
```